# node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts: error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, expo

I just followed the instructions on the link below in order to create a `React Native` app with `TypeScript` support.

https://github.com/mathieudutour/create-react-native-app-typescript

My problem is that when I run: `$ tsc` I get the following error:

```
$ tsc

> react-native-typescript@0.1.0 tsc D:\react-native-typescript
> tsc

node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(164,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(217,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(92,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8885,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8903,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8911,18): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8914,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15764,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15940,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15997,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! react-native-typescript@0.1.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-native-typescript@0.1.0 tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-17T17_20_46_096Z-debug.log
```

It seems that the problems are on packages inside the `node_modules` directory and not on my actual code.

Any idea on how to get the result of `$ tsc` to be clean?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `npm outdated` show anything that's, well, outdated?